# Forcing More Samples in Integrate in R

Tags: r, numerical-integration

```
> integrand <- Vectorize(function(x) {
    ifelse( (x > 0.13) && (x < 0.14), Inf, x^2 )
})

> print( integrate( integrand, 0, 1 ) )
0.3333 with absolute error < 0.0000000000000037
```

is perhaps a little overoptimistic.  Can't blame `integrate()` too much; but my own different problem also features some unpleasant discontinuous functions (though monotonic and not as hugely heterogeneous).  I do need the sampler to get closer to my discontinuities.

Is it possible to ask `integrate()` to sample a lot more before declaring victory?  (Optional argument subdivisons seems to be a maximum (not a minimum) and the tol are already at very low numbers.)

Comment: Does the documentation say something about critical points or maximum step sizes?

Comment: Better to break the integration at the discontinuities, if possible, and call `integrate` multiple times.

Comment: this is the mathematically sensible thing to do.  alas, they sit deep inside expressions, so the human work is moderately costly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pracma::integral`

```
f <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x > 0.13 & x < 0.14, Inf, x^2)
}

pracma::integral(f,0,1)
```

which gives

```
[1] Inf
Warning message:
In .gkadpt(f, a, b, tol = tol) : Infinite or NA function value encountered.
```

Comment: clarification: this is in the `pracma` library.  also has a `no_intervals`, which is a named a bit unfortunately, as it means "number" and not "no".